# Back Button showing image traces

Tags: ios, swift3

```
let backImage:UIImage = (UIImage.init(named: "Back-btn")?.resizableImage(withCapInsets: UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 30, 0, 0)))!
UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setBackButtonBackgroundImage(backImage, for: .normal, barMetrics: .default)
UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setBackButtonTitlePositionAdjustment(UIOffsetMake(-60, -60),for:.default)
```

I want to define appearance of Back button in `appdelegate.swift` at the start of the app. And I don't need the title of the back button too.
I want to remove these traces in the back button.

The above code shows a Back button like following image:
[image]

Comment: So what is your question? Do you wan those traces, or are you getting them but you don't want them?

Comment: I want to remove the traces in the back button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
let backImage:UIImage = (UIImage.init(named: "Back-btn")?.resizableImage(withCapInsets: UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 30, 0, 0)))!
```

with

```
let backImage: UIImage = UIImage(named: "Back-btn")!.stretchableImage(withLeftCapWidth: widthOfTheBackButtonImage, topCapHeight: 0)
```

where `widthOfTheBackButtonImage` would be the width of the image. You also have to ensure that your image has at least 1 point of transparency on the right side.

Comment: 1 point of transparency on right did the trick. Thanks a ton.